# How to reinstall pcspkr

Tags: ubuntu, audio, terminal, modprobe

My computer has 2 audio outputs: a digital speaker and the actual speaker. Unfortunately, a number of my programs will recognize the "digital" speaker not my actual speaker. So, looking for a solution, I accidentally used modprobe -r pcspkr and now I can't figure out how to get it back. Help please?

Answer (score 0):

Reboot. Modules are only loaded in-memory, and the whole device tree is re-detected anew every time you boot; there is no such thing as permanently "installing" or "uninstalling" a device.

Also, like "modprobe -r" removes modules, plain "modprobe" inserts them. You can basically run `modprobe pcspkr` to load the module again.

However, it is *highly* unusual for audio programs to recognize the PC speaker as an output. It is far more likely that your "Digital" output is actually the HDMI or DisplayPort connector (both of which can carry audio as well as video). Some desktops also have an S/PDIF audio port which is also "Digital".

(But if you select the "Digital" output and get sound through the PC beeper, that's... a bit unusual.)

In most cases, you can just specify the default audio output through `pavucontrol` or Ubuntu's sound settings panel, without needing to remove any device in the first place.